# How do I move my main git directory (.git directory) to another folder in my Windows C drive?

Tags: git

When Git was set up in my Windows system, the root folder selected was `/c/Users/anita`. I want to change this location as there are my other files in this location that have nothing to do with my Git projects. I've created a new folder named `Git projects` inside `c/Users/`. How do I make this new location the `.git` directory?

Comment: There is no "**the** git directory", you should have one per project, not something global.

Comment: Okay, so you mean every time I create a new project, it will be within the .git directory but have it's own standalone parent directory and all the files will only be within this standalone directory? Might be too basic a qs but I'm new to this and learning

Answer (score 0):

well in theory you should be able to cut and paste those files to the new folder without problems, what i recommend you is: `copy` the git related files to the new dir and then `update the global enviroment variable` heading to the old folder anita to the new folder you choose

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you could move the `.git` folder (that contains all git data) wherever you want (even if it is highly recommended to move it in an empty folder).

A good advice I could give you before moving the folder is to run a `git gc` to pack all the git objects and make the copy quicker (especially if the repository history is big).

Your biggest concern will be what to do with the files in the working directory.

To solve this issue, the easier is to commit and after, if needed, stash all the uncommitted remaining changes.

That way, you not necessarily need to copy all the working directory files (and so the copy is quicker) and, if needed, you could recover all the files with the 2 commands:

```
git reset --hard Head # restore all files
git stash pop # restore uncommitted changes (if you have created a stash)
```